# Group Duplicate Based on a condition in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has duplicate values. And what I want to do is take sum of  the columns. The only issue I have is I don't want to sum all the duplicate value I want to duplicate based on a column `NewTransaction` in the table.

```
RecoveryKey   DateTime      Duration NewTransaction Variable8   CallTypeID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
7994113912466 12/4/18 16:26 19       Y              152643-5657     -1    
7994113912470 12/4/18 16:26 1168     Y              152643-5657   6390
7994113912751 12/4/18 16:51 2686     N              152643-5657   6390
```

So depending from the table what I am looking to do is select record with `Max(DateTime)` for `Variable8` is duplicate having `NewTransaction == Y`.

And do similar to records having `NewTransaction == N`

If you do that the value that you get is below -

```
RecoveryKey   DateTime      Duration NewTransaction Variable8   CallTypeID
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
7994113912470 12/4/18 16:26 1168     Y              152643-5657    6390
7994113912751 12/4/18 16:51 2686     N              152643-5657    6390
```

What I need for this are `max(RecoveryKey)`, `max(DateTime)`, `Sum(Duration)`. My final result will look like this below

```
RecoveryKey   DateTime      Duration NewTransaction Variable8   CallTypeID
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
7994113912470 12/4/18 16:26 3854     Y              152643-5657    6390
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: You want to know, that you can filter records with `WHERE NewTransaction = 'Y'`?

Comment: @tarheel - I am working with latest version of sql server.

Comment: @stickybit - I know I can filter records but I am looking for a way to write a query which can do what I am looking for.

Comment: @AbdulquadirShaikh: So you're not looking for excluding the records with `NewTransaction = 'Y'`? You want all of them, `'Y'` and `'N'`?

Comment: @stickybit what I want is one record of each 'Y' and 'N'

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is just you want

```
select max(RecoveryKey)
  , distinct DateTime
  , Sum(Duration)
  , NewTransaction, Variable8
  , CallTypeID
from MyTable
group by NewTransaction, Variable8
having datetime = max(datetime);
```

Comment: This is probably what I am looking for but DateTime needs to come in group by clause but DateTime value might defer in seconds or milliseconds. So when I include DateTime in group by it stills give me all 3 rows.

Comment: you cant put date time in group by coz as you said the datetime you want max for each variable8

Comment: Yes, but if I dont it gives an error saying DateTime is not in aggregate or group by.

Comment: put max(DateTime) or i guess even datetime might be same max value else try to add distinct datetime

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, I believe you're trying to do the following two things:

1. Filter down to one record, being the `max([DateTime])`, for every `Variable8` and `NewTransaction` combination.
2. Have the columns show the data contained in the record where the `NewTransaction` value is `Y`, other than showing the total `Duration` from the records that made it through the filter from step 1.

**Answer**

```
with initial_filter as
    (
        select *
        , row_number() over (partition by Variable8, NewTransaction order by [DateTime] desc, RecoveryKey desc) as rnk_a
        , row_number() over (partition by Variable8 order by NewTransaction desc, [DateTime] desc, RecoveryKey desc) as rnk_b
        from MyTable as t
    )
select max(b.RecoveryKey) as RecoveryKey
, max(b.[DateTime]) as [DateTime]
, sum(a.Duration) as Duration
, max(b.NewTransaction) as NewTransaction
, max(b.Variable8) as Variable8
, max(b.CallTypeID) as CallTypeID
from initial_filter as a
left join initial_filter as b on a.RecoveryKey = b.RecoveryKey and b.rnk_b = 1
where a.rnk_a = 1
```

**Results:**

```
+---------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------------+
| RecoveryKey   | DateTime                | Duration | NewTransaction | Variable8   | CallTypeID |
+---------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------------+
| 7994113912470 | 2018-12-04 16:26:00.000 | 3854     | Y              | 152643-5657 | 6390       |
+---------------+-------------------------+----------+----------------+-------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Abdulquadir Shaikh,

Maybe this is what you want.

```
create table test22
(
RecoveryKey varchar(64),
[DateTime] datetime,
Duration int,
NewTransaction varchar(30),
Variable8 varchar(64),
CallTypeID int
)

insert into test22 values
('7994113912466','12/4/18 16:26:00',19,'Y','152643-5657',-1),
('7994113912470','12/4/18 16:26:00',1168,'Y','152643-5657',6390),
('7994113912751','12/4/18 16:51:00',2686,'N','152643-5657',6390)

;WITH CTE AS
(
select
max(RecoveryKey) as RecoveryKey,
max([DateTime]) as [DateTime],
max(Duration) as Duration,
NewTransaction,
Variable8,
max(CallTypeID) as CallTypeID
from test22
group by Variable8,NewTransaction
)
SELECT 
MAX(RecoveryKey) AS RecoveryKey,
MAX([DateTime]) AS [DateTime],
SUM(Duration) AS Duration,
MAX(NewTransaction) AS NewTransaction,
Variable8,
MAX(CallTypeID) AS CallTypeID
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Variable8

--Output
/*
RecoveryKey                                                      DateTime                Duration    NewTransaction                 Variable8                                                        CallTypeID
---------------------------------------------------------------- ----------------------- ----------- ------------------------------ ---------------------------------------------------------------- -----------
7994113912751                                                    2018-12-04 16:51:00.000 3854        Y                              152643-5657                                                      6390
*/
```

If there is any doubt about my reply, please feel free to let me know.

Best Regards,

Will